# How to parse JSON in MYSQL trigger

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to parse JSON format in MYSQL Trigger

```
 {"multicast_id":67784038XXXXXX,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":
[{"message_id":"0:13XXXX280085815%XXXXXXXXX"}]}
```

Actually i am getting this as a response from one of my application and storing in one table (**tbl1**) , so what i am trying to do is create one trigger at that table(**tbl1**) and parse above response and insert respective entries in another table(**tbl2**)

Need to parse above json format in MYSQL Trigger so that i will get all the parameters separately. How can it be done?

Comment: What exactly do you want as output?

Comment: Parsing JSON doesn't sound like a job suitable for mySQL. Where does the data come from?

Answer (score 7):

You can install [common_schema](https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/). Then you should be able to do something like this:

```
select common_schema.extract_json_value(d.table1,'/multicast_id') as multicase_id,
common_schema.extract_json_value(d.table1,'/success') as success,
common_schema.extract_json_value(d.table1,'/failure') as failure,
common_schema.extract_json_value(d.table1,'/canonical_ids') as canonical_ids,
common_schema.extract_json_value(d.table1,'/results') as results,
common_schema.extract_json_value(d.table1,'/message_id') as message_id
from database d;
```

Comment: if you're looking for performance, do not use this, use mysql json udf instead, even though at this moment it's not production approved yet but it works. common schema has too many bugs including parsing minus in the value of the json. Try parsing {"value":"-1"}

Answer (score 2):

Add the code in your application's database model. PHP has a nice built-in function for parsing JSON, whereas this is no job for MySql.

Anyways, storing raw JSON in a table is Bad because it defeats the very purpose of a relational database. Unless you consider the JSON string as a raw string, and do not care of its meaning at database level. Which is not the case apparently.

So do not even bother with storing the JSON string. Parse it from PHP and store the data directly into your `tbl2`. Rebuilding the JSON string from the table with PHP is straightforward and virtually instant (compared to the time it will take to retreive the data from the database).