# How to Parse PHP Searilize data in Mysql Stored Procedure & Looping it

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have below data in Mysql Column (storing all data in serialize form - with comma separated into column) and i want to get/fetch this column data in Mysql stored procedure and want to loop for each data and insert into another trans table.

So if my data like below then i want to insert 7 record in trans table.

```
{"FormBuilderId":"5","vAnswer":"Develeop"},
{"FormBuilderId":"15","vAnswer":"Search Engine"},
{"FormBuilderId":"13","vAnswer":"10-15"},
{"FormBuilderId":"6","vAnswer":"Tester entered"},
{"FormBuilderId":"1","vAnswer":"Female"},
{"FormBuilderId":"14","vAnswer":"Moon.jpg"},
{"FormBuilderId":"12","vAnswer":"TV,dancing and modeling"}
```

My table structure & data is like below in table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `idea_history` (
    `iIdeaHistoryId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `iApplicationId` tinyint(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
    `tAnswerData` text COMMENT 'all answer data store here in json format',
    `dAddedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`iIdeaHistoryId`),
    KEY `iApplicationId` (`iApplicationId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='history comes here' AUTO_INCREMENT=57 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `idea_history`
--

INSERT INTO idea_history (
  iIdeaHistoryId,
  iApplicationId,
  tAnswerData,
  dAddedDate
) 
VALUES
  (
    53,
    2,
    '{"FormBuilderId" : "2","vAnswer":"Environmental Group"},{"FormBuilderId" : "11","vAnswer":"Satelite"},{"FormBuilderId" : "3","vAnswer":"HB"},{"FormBuilderId" : "4","vAnswer":"Dev"},{"FormBuilderId" : "7","vAnswer":"HB"},{"FormBuilderId" : "8","vAnswer":"Balaji Satellite"},{"FormBuilderId" : "10","vAnswer":""}',
    '2014-07-05 19:20:56'
  ),
  (
    54,
    1,
    '{"FormBuilderId":"5","vAnswer":"Hello krishna|kanth double"},{"FormBuilderId":"15","vAnswer":"Website"},{"FormBuilderId":"6","vAnswer":"need to check"},{"FormBuilderId":"13","vAnswer":"20-25"}',
    '2014-07-05 19:20:56'
  ),
  (
    55,
    2,
    '{"FormBuilderId":"11","vAnswer":"comapnay"},{"FormBuilderId":"8","vAnswer":"here am|chw "},{"FormBuilderId" : "10","vAnswer":""},{"FormBuilderId":"9","vAnswer":"Business"}',
    '2014-07-05 19:20:56'
  ) ;
```

I will pass `iIdeaHistoryId` in stored procedure and it will fetch value of `tAnswerData` field and part this value and insert into another trans table.

Could you please guide what i have to change in stored procedure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_variable,'{"',-1),'":"',1) INTO arg_1;
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_variable,'":"',-2),'","',1) INTO arg_2;
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_variable,'","',-1),'":"',1) INTO arg_3;
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_variable,'":"',-1),'"}',1) INTO arg_4;

INSERT INTO trans VALUES (arg_1,arg_2,arg_3,arg_4);
```

or if you want to do it in store procedure add your data here

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS trans$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE trans()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE arg_1,arg_2,arg_3,arg_4 VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR YOUR_SELECT_statement;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN cursor_name;
      my_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_name INTO your_variable;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
          LEAVE my_loop;
        END IF;
          SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_variable,'{"',-1),'":"',1) 
          INTO arg_1 FROM your_table;
          SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_variable,'":"',-2),'","',1) 
          INTO arg_2 FROM your_table;
          SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_variable,'","',-1),'":"',1) 
          INTO arg_3 FROM your_table;
          SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_variable,'":"',-1),'"}',1) 
          INTO arg_4 FROM your_table;
          INSERT INTO trans VALUES (arg_1,arg_2,arg_3,arg_4); 
    END LOOP my_loop;
    CLOSE cursor_name;

    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

for one column you use this

```
DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS trans$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE trans(IN in_iIdeaHistoryId INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE arg_1 VARCHAR(100);
      SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(`tAnswerData`,' ',''),'{"',-1),'":"',1) 
          INTO arg_1 FROM `idea_history` WHERE iIdeaHistoryId=in_iIdeaHistoryId;
          INSERT INTO trans VALUES (arg_1); 
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and call it like this

```
CALL `trans`(53);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I want to loop into stored procedure / function only. I modified my question (submitted table structure) so would you please help what i have to change in stored procedure ?

Comment: i added the procedure

Comment: Yes it is working But It is just inserting one entry into table. 

I found below post that helpful and working for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121304/how-to-parse-json-in-mysql-trigger

Answer (score 0):

This looks like JSON. Use php function json_decode() to store the json data into an array and then you can  use foreach loop on that array.  Inside the loop you can place condition and when its met, you could use insert query to store it in your database.

Does this help you?

If you can explain a bit further what you're trying to do exactly and what are your condition, then i  Can probably give you a better answer.